# Laravel 9 Error Code : 904 Error Message : ORA-00904: "EMAIL"

Tags: android, oracle, api, laravel-9

I created a Laravel API connecting to an Oracle Database my goal is to use it for an android app .

The Error message :
`Error Code : 904 Error Message : ORA-00904: "EMAIL": invalid identifier Position : 49 Statement : select * from (select * from "USERS" where upper(email) = upper(:p0)) where rownum = 1 Bindings : [test@mail.com]`

I installed the yajra oci8 extension to connect to the oracle database .
I checked th config/auth.php
I am using the `laravel php artisan ui bootstrap --auth` for the authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an Oracle error, it won't have anything to do with your client environment.

It means that there is no column named EMAIL (all caps) in the "USERS" table.  Check the column list in that table (`select * from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'USERS'`) and ensure you find a column named EMAIL. If you find one with mixed case, e.g. 'Email' that is a non-standard object name in Oracle and requires the use of double-quotes and exact case-matching. If that's the situation, you can fix it by changing your query to:

```
select * from (select * from "USERS" where upper("Email") = upper(:p0)) where rownum = 1
```